# Binding RValue-References in C++11 Lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, rvalue-reference

Consider the following code:

```
std::function<void()> bind_arg(int&& arg) {
    return [arg]() {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Does this code bind `arg` by value or by rvalue reference? (That is, is this safe, or does it bind a dangling reference?)

Comment: Usually it's called "capturing", not "binding".

Comment: Closed as a dupe of the canonical.  TL;DR: capturing by name without using `&` captures by value (a copy happens).